# Jquery atrr + 2D array issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

i have the following script  and i can't find out how to use the value inside car[0]['img'] inside this $('#img2').attr('src',car[0]['img']);
im a JS noob so please explain me .. why jquery wont accept the 2d array as string value and run the function , and whats the possible solution of my problem ?

```
var id = 0 ;
            var car = new Array();
            car[0]['img'] = "./images/carousel_img_2.jpg";
            car[0]['title'] ="title";
            car[0]['desc'] = 'longer description goes here';
            car[0]['link'] = "http://goeshere.com";
            car[1]['img'] = "./images/carousel_img_3.jpg";
            car[1]['title'] ='title';
            car[1]['desc'] = 'longer description goes here';
            car[1]['link'] = "http://goeshere.com";
            car[2]['img'] = "./images/carousel_img_2.jpg";
            car[2]['title'] ='title';
            car[2]['desc'] = 'longer description goes here';
            car[2]['link'] = "http://goeshere.com";


            function nxt () {   
        $('#img2').fadeOut('slow', function(){

            var img = car[i]['img'] ;
            $('#img2').attr('src',img);
        });
        $('#img2').fadeIn('slow');

            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript has separate datatypes for arrays and dictionaries (a fancy term for key/value stores, like associative arrays. Arrays are either defined through the Array() constructor (as you did) or through square brackets [], while dictionaries are defined with curly braces {}.

An example of an array:

```
var array = ['one', 'two', 'three];
alert ( array[0] ); // "one";
```

An example of a dictioanry:

```
var dict = {
    'one': 'one one',
    'two': 'two two',
    'three': 'three three'
}
alert( dict.one ); // "one one"
```

Try reworking your array definition a bit:

```
var car = [
    {
        'img': './images/carousel_img_2.jpg',
        'title': 'title',
        'desc': 'longer description goes here',
        'link': 'http://goeshere.com'
    },
    {
        'img': './images/carousel_img_3.jpg',
        'title': 'title',
        'desc': 'longer description goes here',
        'link': 'http://goeshere.com'
    },
    {
        'img': './images/carousel_img_2.jpg',
        'title': 'title',
        'desc': 'longer description goes here',
        'link': 'http://goeshere.com'
    }
];
alert( car[0].img ); // "./images/carousel_img_2.jpg"
```

Comment: Also known as JavaScript Object Notation :)

Comment: after i changeed the definition of my array it worked like a charm :) thanks !!

Comment: Glad I could help! For future reference, Javascript debugging is much easier with Firebug's various debugging techniques: 

http://getfirebug.com/js.html

In this case, a simple console.log(car) would have revealed that your array wasn't being defined properly.

Answer (score 0):

First, get rid of the ./ in front of your `img` URLs.  I doubt it's the source of your current troubles, but it's not going to help you out later. Simply drop the forward slash and go with "`images/blah/blah.png`".

Next, where is `i` defined for that `nxt()` function? Right now I see that `id` is set to 0 at the top, but there is no `i` declared. Even if you meant to make it `id` I'm not sure that it would work since you aren't iterating it inside the function.

I believe you want something like:

```
 function nxt (i) {   
    $('#img2').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            var img = car[i]['img'] ;
            $('#img2').attr('src',img);
    });
    $('#img2').fadeIn('slow');

 }
```

Comment: I is declared at the begining of the script but still doesnt work .. even after i removed the ./

Comment: Does it work the first time? Try adding `alert(img)` after you declare that variable. See how many times it alerts and what the value is on each one. Like I said above, it doesn't seem like you are iterating correctly, based on your code.